# How to reload a form from a drop down

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to reload the form, or preferably just the values, by using 'onChange'. There are several elements in the form that needs to be updated when changing the project id.

```
$this->addElement('select', 'project_id', array(
                'label'         => t('Project'),
                'multiOptions'  => $data,
                'filters'       => array('Int'),
                'value'         => 0,
                'required'      => true,
                'disableTranslator' => true,
                'validators'    =>  array(),
                'onChange'      => 'Javascript:window.location.reload(false)'
    ));
```

Comment: You need some Ajax  to do this versus PHP. It is best if you show the rendered HTML and explain that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `onChange` to call a custom javascript function instead - which will change any fields you need to change, and *then* submmit the form.

Comment: I'm gonna go with this solution. Thanks.